# Configure Gnome settings with Debian Live-Build

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, kali-linux, livecd

I'm making a spin of Kali Linux and am following [their guide](https://docs.kali.org/development/live-build-a-custom-kali-iso) while referencing the [Debian Live Build manual](https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/customization-overview.en.html). I'm trying to figure out how I can get a few simple tweaks like application, cursor, icon, and shell themes set. I'd also like to adjust fonts, wallpapers, extensions, and UI scaling among other things. I want all of this to be available both in a fresh installation and in live mode.

So far, the closest thing I've found is a `dconf dump` like shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/522843/450288), but if this is the best way to do what I aim to do, then I'm not sure how I should actually get these settings `dconf load`'ed correctly during the build process.

Comment: You know that Kali is not supposed to be a general purpose distribution?

Comment: I understand, this is specifically for a security club on campus. Treat the question as if it were Debian, all the tooling comes from them.

Answer (score 0):

Ive been designing a custom copy of Kali for a while and prefer the bash script method.
A copy of my live build environment can be found [here](https://github.com/CollectiveIndustries/DRS/blob/master/cw_kali_conf.sh). As ive been working towards a fully branded copy of Kali Ive spent some time rendering images in Pov-Ray as the Desktop, Login, and Grub backgrounds. there's a few files that need to be changed for the desktop background:

`/usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-background.xml`

contains the various desktop resolution settings and image files.